# Checking if this is the last call of a function

Tags: c++11

Basically what I want is sort of the opposite of [**std::call_once**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), I need to have some code, inside function `foo` for example, run only at the last call of foo preferably without some sort of lazy call mechanisms.

```
void foo()
{
    ...
    if( magic )
       do stuff
}

foo();
foo();
foo(); // magic will only be true here
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: If you could have your program predict the future, then yes it would, and soon you would drown in huge piles of money.

Comment: Oh well, I knew it was a long shot. I'll go back to working on my time machine now

Answer (score 2):

This magic would be magic, it's not possible in this world.

However, I guess, your problem is how to do required cleanup, and that is possible. There are at least three distinct mechanism that I can think of:

1. Register a cleanup handler with `atexit()`.
2. Define a function with `__attribute__((destructor))`.
3. Put your cleanup in the destructor of a class and create a static object of that class.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible. The only way to know for sure that nobody will ever call `foo` again is a) solve the Halting Problem b) call foo on program termination.

Comment: `atexit` handlers can still call `foo`.